# Wordpress - Yoast SEO - robots.txt

Tags: wordpress, seo, robots.txt

I was just reading up on Yoast website [here](https://yoast.com/wordpress-robots-txt-example/) on how the correct robots.txt file should look like with the latest SEO practices. In their example Yoast uses the following:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /suggest/?*
```

What exactly does line `Disallow: /suggest/?*` do?

Comment: Based of the answer below ..  is there a particular reason why Yoast uses `/suggest/` in their robots file? Is this meant to be just a placeholder or does the `suggest` actually have a partiular meaning??

Answer (score 1):

> What exactly does line Disallow: /suggest/?* do?

`disallow` and `?*` will block search engines from accessing any URL that has a `?` in it.

Altogether  Disallow: /suggest/?* will block search engines from accessing urls such as  `yourwebsiteexample.com/suggest/?any.php=34`

in other words, it will not block search engines from accessing other urls having `?`

`yourwebsiteexample.com/anyother/?any.php=34`  <--- this will be crowed by search engines

more examples
https://geoffkenyon.com/how-to-use-wildcards-robots-txt/

Comment: Based on that article, shouldn't it be `/*?` ? (Based on intuition I thought it was `/*?*`.) Otherwise, good explanation!

Comment: Thanks @Aravinda and @EsaJonkien .. is there a particular reason why Yoast uses `/suggest/` in their robots file? Is this meant to be just a placeholder or does the `suggest` actually have a partiular meaning??

Comment: suggest should be example directory. no specific meaning. if you dont have one called suggest and if you dont have above requirement to block search engines from accessing any URL that has a ? , u don't have to use it